# If statement not working, skipping over to else

Tags: java, if-statement

My "if" statement doesnt seem to be working, whatever I put in always seems to default to my "else" statement. Such as if I put in the integer "1" or "2", which have "if" statements associated with them, it still defaults to "else". Any help would be appreciated :)

```
String number = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Would you like a custom loop count or an infinite? 1.  Custom   2. Infinite"); //test choice
n = Integer.parseInt(number);
while (n < 0 || n > 2) {
    if (n == 1) {


        String number2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many times would you like to loop?");
        integer = Integer.parseInt(number2);
        while (integer < 0) {
            while (x < integer) {
                g.drawString("hi", 200, y);

                x += 1;
                y = y + 40; //test
            }//end while
        }
    }//end if 
    else if (n == 2) {
        while (1 == 1);
    }//end if   
    else;
}
g.drawString("Please pick a valid choice", 200, 200);
```

Comment: You know, proper indentation would be great...

Comment: This code is just a big bag of bugs. Indent following conventions and pay attention to the `;` : they have a meaning.

Comment: looks like homework. I hope your prof didn't teach you to code like that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the block after

```
while (n<0 || n>2)
```

is executed, you know that `n` is either < 0 or > 2. Therefore it can't be equal to 1 or 2 and the `else` block is executed, **which happens to be empty** because it is followed by a `;`.

That's not mentioning the few weird statements found in your code ;-)

ps: I have edited your post to add proper indentation to your code and include `{` and `}`. It might look a little clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

```
else;
```

That's very wrong.
You don't have a else statement, it means the following line of code is executed.

This line is very bad too :

```
while (1==1);
```

Please indent following the norms and remove the unwanted ';'.